# Chrome and IE Virtual hosts subdomains pointing to wrong directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

`Firefox` brings up the correct pages, but `IE` and `Chrome` both bring up the default page.

I am running `Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)` on `CentOS 6.5`

I have a `virtual.conf` in the `conf.d` folder with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.net/public_html/
ServerName www.domain.net
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
ServerName www.domain.com
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.ca/public_html/
ServerName www.domain.ca
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know what may be causing the issue?

I add a new block without the www for each one, example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
ServerName domain.com
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Looks like browser-side caching, try Ctrl-F5 on IE, Chrome

Comment: I added a new block for each `domain` without the `www` for the `ServerName`. Is this the proper procedure?

Comment: While it'll work (and there may be reasons for doing so) you should be using the `ServerAlias` directive.  I'm having a hard time following what this has to do with your original question however.

Comment: It had nothing to do with firefox bringing up the right site. I just happen to be putting in the www for firefox and not in chrome or ie. Ignorance at its best! Thank you for `ServerAlias` that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser dns caching problem. Try to clear browser cache or anonymous navigation on Chrome to test your apache settings.
Btw you should use ServerAlias directive, as others have commented.

Comment: that is what my problem was, I didnt have any type of server alias